# Bootstrap 4 : Align 5 cards in each new lin filled with cards

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Here's my "Bootstrap configuration":

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-3">              
      <div class="card mb-3 cardtrans">
// Here goes card-body / header and all the other stuff inside it. 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I display each new card using a PHP loop.

I used the code above to align 4 cards in the same line. I want to see 5 cards in each new line. What classes should I use? Or do I need additional CSS code?

Answer (score 0):

**For Bootstrap 4.6.x**

Use `row-cols-lg-5` from [Row Columns](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/grid/#row-columns) where you do not need to set the column width for each element. Instead you just set the row columns count and bootstrap will wrap the overflow to the next row.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row row-cols-lg-5">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="card mb-3 cardtrans">Card 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="card mb-3 cardtrans">Card 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="card mb-3 cardtrans">Card 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="card mb-3 cardtrans">Card 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="card mb-3 cardtrans">Card 5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="card mb-3 cardtrans">Card 6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```